# Show Equation(1.1) instead of (1.1)

Tags: equations

I want to know, how can I write `Equation(1.1)` in LaTeX instead of `(1.1)` ?

e.g. Normally it shows

```
            a+b                  (1.1)
```

I want to print like following

```
            a+b                   Equation (1.1)
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.stack...

Answer (score 3):

The `mathtools` package defines commands for that:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newtagform{long}{Equation\,(}{)}
\usetagform{long}

\counterwithin{equation}{chapter}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{1}
\begin{equation}
a+b = b + a
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice suggestion....

Comment: @MadyYuvi: yours is fine too (+1).

Comment: ha ha ha ... :-D Much thanks...

Answer (score 2):

As you are not providing any `MWE`, I assume that you are using standard template. Below tags may helps you:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{\text{Equation }(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
a+b
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: My compliments: I agree with Bernard.